# Base url sever issues while porting wordpress website

Tags: php, wordpress

I had installed wordpress on my client server . And the path was www.domainname.com/demo . 
Now i moved all the files to the root directory and the website is running fine along with the admin panel .

But for some reason the slideshow gallery and all the images are not loading properly . I tried changing the base url wherever required but the images still do not seem to load.

Is there anything i am missing out on ? . 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where is your slideshow image coming from? I mean from post?

Comment: I have used a slideshow plugin where i can upload and delete images.

Comment: Can you give me plugin URL ?

Answer (score 0):

in your wp_options table please change the value of the following options to the new address.

1. bp_album_base_url
2. siteurl
3. home

of this does not solve your problem, then please search in your database, may be your slideshow plugin saving full address of the images in database like http://yourdomain.com/...., please confirm these steps hopefully your problem will be resolved.

Comment: there is nothing such as bp_album_base_url , i have changed the home and the siteurl paths to my domain_name. Still does not seem to work.

Comment: sorry try the other two, this is i case of buddypress installation